# Start android service immediately

Tags: android, service

I have an app with an integrated music player. This player plays music in a service...

Now my app is a sports app, so the user listens to music and sometimes, timer events occur and play a alarm sound. I want to use the service for playing these sound because I want to stop the normal music, play the alarm and resume the music.

My problem is, sometimes (not very often), there is a quite long delay... Of some seconds...

How can I avoid this?

*Btw., I implemented a Do-Not-Disturb Mode, so I can't use audio focus if this mode is enabled. I have to manually pause the player only for internal alarms and resume afterwards...*

Answer (score 1):

You could start the `Service` at the boot, and then simply bind to it whenever you need it. Checkout the docs to learn how a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) works.

Comment: I use a service that sometimes is bound to an activity... I even did my tests while it was bound and running in the foreground... BUT, the delay did happen (and that only sometimes) while the service was bound and running in the foreground...